# Why query params are not encode using Retrofit2 android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

My problem to encode the query param before sending to the server. I am using Retrofit2 API service client.

My Request : `@GET("/Categories/70/{category}")`

```
fun getPLPList(@Path("category") category: String, @QueryMap(encoded = true) map: Map<String, String>): Observable<PLPModel>
```

I already enable `flag encoded=truitut` its doesn't work for me.

Api Request: https://api-test.net/Categories/CL/70/cat450012?orderBy=5

Expected Output: https://api-test.azurewebsites.net/Categories/CL/70/cat450012?orderBy%3D5

Comment: Is that really what you want to get? It means you have one query parameter with name `orderBy=5` and no value.

Comment: Yes OrderBy=5 is my query param and i want to be encode form of query param